# Error while using autoincrement keyword in sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

Hi i am developing android application, And now i have to use sqlite database to store some data in the phone. Now when i create database without autoincrement keyword. But when i use this keyword error comes which says

> "java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{abc.tt/abc.tt.Home}:
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "autoincrement": syntax
>   error: create table calSimpleNote (_id integer PRIMERY KEY
>   autoincrement , Cal_Id TEXT , User_ID INTEGER , Cal_Date TEXT , Note
>   TEXT,Involvers TEXT, DeleteReason TEXT ,Create_Date TEXT ,Changed_date
>   TEXT,EmailInvolvers TEXT,RemindSameDay INTEGER, RemindAllDay
>   INTEGER,RemindBeforeDays INTEGER );" .

[Here is my code to create database.](http://pastebin.com/YBgq4gs0)
Error comes while creating the database. Do help me if anyone have any idea. Thank you.

I have use following link for refrence.[This](http://moazzam-khan.com/blog/?tag=android-sqlite)

I am using this code to insert but i is not incrementing.

public long insertCalSimpleNote(String noteId,int userId,String cal_date,String note,String Involved,String DeleteReason,String Create_Date,
                                    String Changed_date,String emailInvolvers,int remindSameday,int remindAllday,int remindBeforeday){

```
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();

    initialValues.put("_Id", 0);
    initialValues.put("Cal_Id", noteId);
    initialValues.put("User_ID", userId);
    initialValues.put("Cal_Date", cal_date);
    initialValues.put("Note", note);
    initialValues.put("Involvers", Involved);
    initialValues.put("DeleteReason", DeleteReason);
    initialValues.put("Create_Date", Create_Date);
    initialValues.put("Changed_date", Changed_date);
    initialValues.put("EmailInvolvers", emailInvolvers);
    initialValues.put("RemindSameDay", remindSameday);
    initialValues.put("RemindAllDay", remindAllday);
    initialValues.put("RemindBeforeDays", remindBeforeday);

    return db.insert("calSimpleNote", null, initialValues);
}

It set 0 at every row.

//Create Table
private static final String CREATE_SIMPLENOTE = "create table calSimpleNote (_id integer PRIMERY KEY, Cal_Id TEXT , User_ID INTEGER , Cal_Date TEXT , Note TEXT,Involvers TEXT, "+
                                                "DeleteReason TEXT ,Create_Date TEXT ,Changed_date TEXT,EmailInvolvers TEXT, "+ 
                                                "RemindSameDay INTEGER, RemindAllDay INTEGER,RemindBeforeDays INTEGER );"; 
@Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
    {
        db.execSQL(CREATE_SIMPLENOTE);
    }
```

Comment: This line is not required: 
initialValues.put("_Id", 0)

Comment: I HAVE REMOVED IT. But den there isn't any value inserted.It insert " " only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
//Create Table
private static final String CREATE_SIMPLENOTE = "create table calSimpleNote (_id integer primary key autoincrement, Cal_Id TEXT , User_ID INTEGER , Cal_Date TEXT , Note TEXT,Involvers TEXT, "+
                                                "DeleteReason TEXT ,Create_Date TEXT ,Changed_date TEXT,EmailInvolvers TEXT, "+ 
                                                "RemindSameDay INTEGER, RemindAllDay INTEGER,RemindBeforeDays INTEGER );";
```

& this:

```
public long insertCalSimpleNote(String noteId,int userId,String cal_date,String note,String Involved,String DeleteReason,String Create_Date, String Changed_date,String emailInvolvers,int remindSameday,int remindAllday,int remindBeforeday){

    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();


    initialValues.put("Cal_Id", noteId);
    initialValues.put("User_ID", userId);
    initialValues.put("Cal_Date", cal_date);
    initialValues.put("Note", note);
    initialValues.put("Involvers", Involved);
    initialValues.put("DeleteReason", DeleteReason);
    initialValues.put("Create_Date", Create_Date);
    initialValues.put("Changed_date", Changed_date);
    initialValues.put("EmailInvolvers", emailInvolvers);
    initialValues.put("RemindSameDay", remindSameday);
    initialValues.put("RemindAllDay", remindAllday);
    initialValues.put("RemindBeforeDays", remindBeforeday);

    return db.insert("calSimpleNote", null, initialValues);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A column declared INTEGER PRIMARY KEY will autoincrement bydeafult.

I stole it from [here](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q1):

> Short answer: A column declared INTEGER PRIMARY KEY will
>   autoincrement.
>
> Here is the long answer: If you declare a column of a table to be
>   INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, then whenever you insert a NULL into that column
>   of the table, the NULL is automatically converted into an integer
>   which is one greater than the largest value of that column over all
>   other rows in the table, or 1 if the table is empty. (If the largest
>   possible integer key, 9223372036854775807, then an unused key value is
>   chosen at random.) For example, suppose you have a table like this:
>
> ```
> CREATE TABLE t1(
>   a INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
>   b INTEGER
> );
> ```
>
> With this table, the statement
>
> ```
> INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(NULL,123);
> ```
>
> is logically equivalent to saying:
>
> ```
> INSERT INTO t1 VALUES((SELECT max(a) FROM t1)+1,123);
> ```

Answer (score 1):

There is no `autoincrement` keyword in `SQLite`, that is why you are getting an error.

A column declared `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` will autoincrement.

If you declare a column of a table to be `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`, then whenever you insert a NULL into that column of the table, the NULL is automatically converted into an integer which is one greater than the largest value of that column over all other rows in the table, or 1 if the table is empty. For example :

```
CREATE TABLE mytable(
  column1 INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  column2 INTEGER
);
```

here  column1 is auto-increment.

Comment: One way you can try for just test. Insert the first row specifying explicitly the row id you want to start with. SQLite will then insert row ids that are higher than the previous highest.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite doesn't have an autoincrement option.

You can either :

1) create a column of the type INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (it will be automatically incremented)
2) create a column named ROWID and live it null on inserts.
3) create you own and implement the autoincrement option through your code (not recommended)